# The sum of the measures of the angles formed at the tips of a star.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, polygons

First observe that the star may be separated into a single $n$-gon and $n$ triangles.

\begin{align*}
 (n-2) \cdot 180  &= \text{ sum of interior angles of the $n$-gon } \\
  n \cdot 180  &= \text{sum of interior angles of all the $n$ triangles} \\
\end{align*}

The interior angles of the $n$ triangles not part of the tips may be labeled with $x_1, .... , x_n$ , using them twice where vertical angles arise.

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n 2x_j = \text{ sum of all angles of the $n$ triangles not part of the tips of the star}$$

Now see that each vertex of the on the the perimeter of the star that isn't a tip "represents" $360$ degrees. There are $n$ of these, so in total there is

$$ n \cdot 360 = 2n \cdot 180 \text{ degrees } $$ accounting for all of them.

If we exploit the vertical angles corresponding to the interior angles of the $n$-gon, we obtain

$$ \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n 2x_j \right] + 2(n-2) \cdot 180 = 2n \cdot 180 $$

Then $\sum_{j=1}^n 2x_j  = 4 \cdot 180 $. To obtain the sum of the angles in the corners of the star, we simply do

$$ n \cdot 180 - 4 \cdot 180 = 180 \left[ n-4 \right], \, \text{ for } n \geq 5 $$

Comment: Feel free to let me know about any errors! Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of "star" that you are using?  In what way does a tip "represent" $360^\circ$?  I haven't been able to make sense of that.